# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class and NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

Trying to show the upload form after clicking on a question.

I suspect there's something with @question.video because when I type "Question" in the rails console, video is not a reference.

What else could be the issue?  In my Video controller and /video/_form, the below code works for @video;

Shouldn't it work for @question.video as well?

Thank you for your time,

```
<%= form_for(@question.video, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
<p><%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %> 

<%= f.label :image, "Attach here" %> <br />
<%= f.file_field :image %>
</p>
<p><%= f.submit 'Upload Video' %></p>
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace please

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that (question belongs_to: video) in the question model and in the video model it (has_many: questions) and not vice versa so you can't just swap the syntax.